# Step into project classes while debugging

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to tell Idea step into only project classes (package `com.myproject.*`). I know that I can tell Idea exclude packages by pattern (*) but it's too inconvenient to write all possible packages except mine.

***updated***
After excluding all possible packages Intellij doesn't step into functions of the same class. It look like while stepping in function it meets proxy class with excluded package and ignores all functions called by this proxy (including my function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible right now, please [vote for the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-54807).

Comment: 11 years hoping in vain... the issue is still open, without a serious reaction from JetBrains :(